# Can you use REST API to upload photos from your phone onto SharePoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, mobile

I need to develop a mobile web application that allows users to upload photos onto a SharePoint photo library or document library using REST API. For some reason, users can upload photos from their computers, but it doesn't work when users upload photos from their smartphone/tablet. It goes to my ajax success function and I don't get any error messages which is strange too. Does anyone know why or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In theory is should work the same, have you attached chromes remote debugging as step through the code to determine what is occurring a bit better. Is it just certain file types?

Comment: It seems to only happen with images. I tried using Chrome's remote debugging, but it won't let me use the file input; it just crashes whenever I click on it.

Comment: the browser crashes? turn on preserve console.logs if the page is refreshing